# ivy or maven? which one to use?

Tags: maven-2, ant, maven, ivy

which one is better? Ant-IVY or Maven?.

Comment: It all depends on your needs. Both products can be used with success.

Comment: this is hardly a question to which you can give a objectively correct answer. please read the faq at http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 4):

That really depends. From my experience I would suggest to use

- Maven for new projects - it is simply easier and less to worry about
- Ivy for old projects which have complicated and established build process in ANT - the conversion to maven may be real pain

It also serves slightly different purposes. Ivy is dependency management only and adds basically just some ant tasks (you are still in ANT) where Maven does lots of extra stuff (packaging, deploying, site generation etc.).

Comment: Thanks for your succinct answer. It helped me understand the role of two technologies in the build process.